# Elegant way with Jquery to track document clicks persisted

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, mousedown

I'm trying to persist some data which is how many times a user does the mousedown on the entire document.  The problem is dealing with redirects and freshing pages which with my means lose all persisted data. This is a bit of a hack I created.. There must be a more elegant way with javascript/jquery to persist data and check the value on redirects?

```
       $(document).click(function(m) {
if ($.cookie('_click_count') == null) {
  $.cookie('_click_count', 1, {path: '/'});
}
else {
  $.cookie('_click_count', 2, {path: '/'});
}
```

});

```
$(document).mousedown(function(e) {
 if ($.cookie('_click_count') == 2) {
     $("#freeModal").appendTo("body");
     $("#freeModal").modal('show');
   }
  }
});
```

Comment: You want to get data where user goes from your site?

Comment: The idea is just to keep a running tab/track of how many times the user has clicked on the site, and persist this data even with redirects.   The reason being is that after 10 clicks on the site, I want a particular action to happen.

Comment: javascript has no state saving...cookie, localstorage or server storage are main options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think you want increment you click counts.

So, you can track it like this:

```
$(document).on("click", function(){

    var click_count = parseInt($.cookie('_click_count')); // get clicks from cookie

    if (click_count < 10 && click_count != NaN) // if count was started
        $.cookie('_click_count', click_count + 1, {path: '/'}); //  increase clicked count

    else if (click_count === 10) // if you reached at 10
        // do action

    else // if you want to start again
        $.cookie('_click_count', 1, {path: '/'});

})
```

Comment: need to check for cookie before using parseInt or will throw error, or wrap in try/catch

Comment: if there is not cookie it returns "NaN"

Comment: Will this solution work on the same page without refreshing?  For example clicking 10 times on links that do not refresh or redirect (example: bootstrap tabs)